# mysql group by date and left join table used group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to query two tables now, use the left connection, first use the group by date in the main table, the date is grouped according to the week, and now I also want to use the same date to group in the join table of join. How to query this?
now I am doing this

```
select 
case 
 when order.time BETWEEN '2018-7-27' and '2018-8-3' then '7.27-8.2'
 when order.time BETWEEN '2018-8-3' and '2018-8-10' then '8.3-8.9'
 else "--" end ptime,
 payment.uid, payment.time
 from order  
 left join
 (select uid, time, from payment where create_time between '2018-7-27' and '2018-8-10') payment on payment.uid = order.uid
 where order.time between '2018-7-13' and '2018-8-10'

  +----------+-------+-----------------------+
  |   date   | uid   | time                  |
  +----------+-------+-----------------------+
  | 7.27-8.2 |    42 |   2018-07-27 22:08:22 |  
  | 7.27-8.2 |    42 |   2018-07-27 22:08:22 |              
  | 8.3-8.9  |    50 |   2018-08-04 14:19:00 |         
  | 8.3-8.9  |    50 |   2018-08-04 14:19:00 |      
  | 8.3-8.9  |    76 |   2018-07-28 14:20:00 |       
  | 8.3-8.9  |    76 |   2018-07-28 14:12:00 |         
  | 8.3-8.9  |    76 |   2018-07-28 13:12:00 |          
  | 8.3-8.9  |    88 |   2018-07-28 19:29:00 |       
  | 8.3-8.9  |    98 |   2018-08-09 14:39:00 |           
  +----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

except output:

```
  +----------+-------+-----+
  |   date   | uid   | time|
  +----------+-------+-----+
  | 7.27-8.2 |    42 |   2 |                
  | 8.3-8.9  |    50 |   2 |         
  | 8.3-8.9  |    76 |   3 |       
  | 8.3-8.9  |    88 |   0 |       
  | 8.3-8.9  |    98 |   1 |        
  +----------+-------+-----+
```

But in this way, the payment time is not grouped according to the date of the order.
Grouping rules are still on the order table.

How do I apply a date grouping to two tables, and do the same grouping of the pay table deduplication? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you please share your expected output

Comment: Ok, I have already edited, can you help me see it, thank you

Comment: check answer please

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
select p1.ptime, p2.uid, count(p2.uid) (
select 
case 
when order.time BETWEEN '2018-7-27' and '2018-8-3' then '7.27-8.2'
when order.time BETWEEN '2018-8-3' and '2018-8-10' then '8.3-8.9'
else "--" end ptime
from order  
where order.time between '2018-7-13' and '2018-8-10' group by ptime) p1
left join 
(select 
case 
when payment.time BETWEEN '2018-7-27' and '2018-8-3' then '7.27-8.2'
when payment.time BETWEEN '2018-8-3' and '2018-8-10' then '8.3-8.9'
else "--" end p2time,
count(payment.uid) uid_cnt
from order  
left join
 (select uid, time, from payment where create_time between '2018-7-27' and 
'2018-8-10') payment on payment.uid = order.uid
where order.time between '2018-7-13' and '2018-8-10' group by p2time) p2
on p2.p2time = p1.ptime
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need aggregate function `count`

```
     select uid,date(ptime) as date,count(payment.time) as time 
  from    
             ( select 
            case 
             when order.time BETWEEN '2018-7-27' and '2018-8-3' then '7.27-8.2'
             when order.time BETWEEN '2018-8-3' and '2018-8-10' then '8.3-8.9'
             else "--" end ptime,
             payment.uid, payment.time
             from order  
             left join
             (select uid, time, from payment where create_time between '2018-7-27' and '2018-8-10') payment on payment.uid = order.uid
             where order.time between '2018-7-13' and '2018-8-10'
            ) as t group by uid,date(ptime)
```

Comment: @yehyork just check my answer used in upper in your query a sub-query and group by